# How to fix jagged edges on conic-gradient

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-gradients, conic-gradients

I got a progress bar that I build using conic-gradient, but its edges look not sharp. I've found some suggestions online but none of them seem to work so far.
Here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/h79zgjas/3/) of the whole progress bar.

```
 background-image: conic-gradient(
    transparent var(--min-degrees),
    #00ACEE var(--min-degrees) var(--progress, 0),
    transparent var(--progress, 0)
  );
```

Any idea how I can smooth its edges?

Thanks

Comment: always have 1px/2px between the colors to avoid this

Comment: @TemaniAfif sorry, not sure I understand. Can you expand it? How would it apply to this?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/qrep257w/2/

Comment: @TemaniAfif ah, I now get it...it works, thanks a lot!

Comment: sadly this isn't perfect 1px antialiasing

Answer (score 1):

You do not state in your question which browser you are using, but I can reproduce the issue in Chromium 118. The problem is that Chromium does not anti-alias CSS gradients. The corresponding bug report is [here](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=408528). This was first filed over 9 years ago, and there is still no fix.

As others have commented, you can implement a small amount of blending between the hard stops as a workaround. You can use [`calc()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc) in CSS gradients, which makes this easier.

I am also seeing this issue on Firefox. I submitted a report [here](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1860310).

Answer (score 0):

```scss
// BEFORE:
conic-gradient(#000000 80%, #ffffff 0)

//AFTER
conic-gradient(#000000 80%, #ffffff 80.15%)
```